# a new(?) operation using products of multiplicities

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, terminology, prime-factorization

Does the operation
$$n \odot m := \prod_{p \text{ prime}} p^{v_p(n) \cdot v_p(m)}$$
on positive integers have a common name? Has this operation been studied somewhere?

Notice that $\odot$ is associative and commutative, but it has no neutral element. It satisfies the distributive law $n \odot (m \cdot k) = (n \odot m) \cdot (n \odot k)$. Two positive integers $n,m$ are coprime if and only if $n \odot m = 1$. If $p$ is a prime number and $k,\ell$ are two integers, then $p^k \odot p^\ell = p^{k \cdot \ell}$.

Comment: Let $S$ be the set of eventually-zero sequences of nonnegative integers, which forms a group under componentwise addition. Then $S$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of positive integers, under the map $(s_1,s_2,\dots) \mapsto p_1^{s_1}p_2^{s_2}\cdots$. The set $S$ has a natural multiplication on it (componentwise) that turns it into a ring. Your operation is the corresponding "multiplication" operation on the positive integers, that turns it into a ring together with the "addition" that comes from usual multiplication.

Comment: @GregMartin: Yes, sure.